# Installing XML::Parser requires expat.h

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan, yum

I'm working on a project that requires all third-party (read: CPAN) perl modules to be installed in a perforce repository, so that any code that depends on them can be successfully run without anyone else needing to manually install them.  I ran into an issue though when trying to install XML::Parser.  I use cpanminus to install my CPAN modules, so I ran `cpanm -L . XML::Parser` in the desired directory (this has worked before with other modules) and got the error:

```
Expat.xs:12:19: error: expat.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm used to using Ubuntu and apt-get, but at work I have to use RedHat and I'm not sure how to install expat to a local directory.  I ran `yum search expat` and got

```
expat.i386 : A library for parsing XML.
expat.x86_64 : A library for parsing XML.
```

So I tried `yum install --installroot=. expat.i386` and got the following errors:

```
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
error: cannot open Packages index using db3 - No such file or directory (2)
error: cannot open Packages database in ./var/lib/rpm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in ?
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 309, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 157, in main
    base.getOptionsConfig(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 187, in getOptionsConfig
    self.conf
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 665, in <lambda>
    conf = property(fget=lambda self: self._getConfig(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 240, in _getConfig
    self._conf = config.readMainConfig(startupconf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/config.py", line 804, in readMainConfig
    yumvars['releasever'] = _getsysver(startupconf.installroot, startupconf.distroverpkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/config.py", line 877, in _getsysver
    idx = ts.dbMatch('provides', distroverpkg)
TypeError: rpmdb open failed
```

What am I doing wrong?  Also, once I do get expat installed, I'm not sure how I would tell cpanm where to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a workaround.  I installed XML::Simple instead.  At first it looked like XML::Simple required XML::Parser, but after some looking found out that it requires either XML::Parser OR XML::SAX, so I installed XML::SAX instead and got XML::Simple working.  Good enough for my needs.

Answer (score 5):

I see a couple of things that could help get you on the right path. First, the package you want is called `expat-devel`. Also, I think you need to provide an absolute path to the --installroot option, and you probably don't need to provide the package extension to yum unless this is relevant to how you building these modules (i.e., you can usually just do `yum install expat-devel`).

It also looks like something may be wrong with your rpmdb, since you got the "rpmdb open failed" message. You can run `yum check` to look for problems in rpmdb, but beyond that I can't say anything specifically going on with the package manager. Perhaps others can help more with that aspect.

Comment: I tried `yum install --installroot=[absolute path] expat-devel` and it says `No package expat-devel available.`  In fact, even if I try it with expat.i386, I get the same error

Comment: What version of Red Hat are you using? I see expat-devel with `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9 (Tikanga)` and `Fedora release 17 (Beefy Miracle)`. Perhaps this is another issue with your rpmdb?

Comment: `lsb_release -i -r` says `Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer Release: 5.6`

Comment: This appears to be a common issue (I just searched "yum rpmdb open failed" and found a lot of discussions). I would post what I found here but you may want to read for yourself in the right context. After that is resolved, you can probably proceed with installing `expat-devel`.

Comment: The answers I found seemed to suggest that I should rebuild the db, but I tried that and nothing changed.  I searched for a rpm download for expat-devel online, but I didn't find anything as old as 5.6

Comment: It sounds like you found an alternate route. Another option to consider for solving your original problem is to try downloading an older version of expat from sourceforge and compiling it for your system. That is, if you care to get XML::Parser working, but it may be extra work if XML::Simple does everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

just install expat by downloading it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/expat/ and 
    $ ./config
    $ make
    $ make install